# file upload on cross domain using blueimp in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, cross-domain, blueimp

I am using blueimp plugin for uploading files on server. Its working fine on local server but not on remote server. I set xhrfields true but same result. My code in main.js as follows

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url:'http://remoteserver/dir/default.aspx',
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mpeg|mpg|avi|mp4|mov|flv|wmv)$/i,
        sequentialUploads: true,

    });
```

Please guide how to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same problem. But when I change WithCredentials to false. It works for me. Try to do this.

Comment: but in documents every where written that it should be true.

Comment: Yes I know. Due to this i was worried about. But when i set it to false it works. Try once